# How to specify .runsettings file in MSTest commandline?

Tags: .net, mstest

I am following guidelines from [MSDN - 
Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj635153.aspx).

I have created `Default.runsettings` in my solution, since I use a script to run my tests, I need to specify the settings file in `MSTest.exe` commandline.

However, according to [MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#runconfig), I have option `/testsettings`, but this is to specify a `.testsettings` file which is the old way as described in the first page I linked.

How to specify a `.runsettings` file for `MSTest` command line?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mstest.exe` is the old way to run tests from the command line. You should be using [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).

`VSTest.Console.Exe` takes a `/Settings:[ file name ]` command line argument which should be a `.runsettings` file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... what happens when you have no control over whether you run mstest or vstest?

Comment: @redspidermkv Why don't you have control over that? Runsettings are supported for vstest.console.exe

Comment: In my case, the build team runs cc.net and still use mstest. So have no choice but to use mstest from the command line..